# How to use sharpSvn to exclude files which i don't want to commit via c#?

Tags: c#, file, sharpsvn

i have tried to exclude in svn property and global-ignore list but all failed, is there any way to do this in coding via c#?

Answer (score -1):

Just specified which files should be committed, and use `SvnDepth.Empty` in your `SvnCommitArgs`. Excluding, and ignore lists are just for ignoring new files (mostly to allow you to `svn add *` on the command line, without adding files that shouldn't be in svn)